# Oracle: Assistance in breaking apart a complex date string

Tags: string, oracle, date

I have a complex date string being read from a csv file.  The format is unable to be processed by Oracle's TO_DATE function.  Looking for an efficient method to break this string apart and return a date object, to insert into a DATE column.  The suggested option of using TO_DATE with 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM' does not work. Not variation of this will break up this particular string. Hence the need for a custom function. I have also tried with the 'HH.MI.SS.SSSSS AM' format which also does not work.  I have found that if I drop the fractional seconds, it will work.  If I run a regex to drop that portion, it should convert as expected.

The string is formatted as: 21-OCT-04 01.03.23.966000 PM

My initial thought is to break up by space first, resulting in three sub strings.
Then break the first substring by - and the second by ., and load the resulting pieces into a DATE object directly.

Is there a better method I could use?

Thank you, Allan

Comment: so you don't need to keep the `.96000` portion of the timestamp? If so, please edit your Q to indicate this. Good luck.

Comment: How about using a regexp_replace to delete the ".966000" portion, and then apply a conversion to the remainder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use what you have, which is a timestamp literal, to create a timestamp, and then cast it "as date":

```
select 
  cast(to_timestamp('21-OCT-04 01.03.23.966000 PM', 'dd-MON-rr hh.mi.ss.ff AM') as date) dt
from dual;

DT
----------------------
2004/10/21 01:03:23 PM
```

(The output format depends on my specific session NLS_DATE_FORMAT, which I actually changed for this illustration to `'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mi:ss AM'`.)

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick.
Finding that dates in Oracle are extremely complex and non-intuitive. I really appreciate the assistance.